# Count some images Using Selenium

Tags: selenium, count

I have the code below and want to count only the images in "galeria003" (I have others galleries with imgs on the page)

```
<div id="classepai" class="carrossel">
<div class="galeria003">
<div class="conjuntoimgs">
    <div class="imagem_item">
        <div>
            <a href="https://localhost/pagina1.html"><img src="https://localhost/foto1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imagem_item">
        <div>
            <a href="https://localhost/pagina2.html"><img src="https://localhost/foto2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>  
</div>
<div class="galeria004">
<div class="conjuntoimgs">
    (...)
</div>  
</div>
```

I tried with the code below, but it returns to me all the images on the page.

```
public int galeria03() {
     List<WebElement> lista03 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
     int count = 0;
     for(WebElement e : lista03) {

       count++;
     }
 return count;
```

Comment: In Python there is the method find_elements_by_class_name that could suit you. I guess you can find similar binding in your language (C/Java?). Then you get your image inside of this, either using your original code or something like innerHTML or text and using regexes to find the urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below xpath to get all image tag present in "galeria003"

```
List<WebElement> lista03 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='galeria003']//img"));
```

And print the total image element

```
System.out.println(lista03.size());
```